# Why are the paragraph and header tags forcing their parent elements to move?

Tags: html, css, paragraph, html-heading

I only recently discovered the viewHeight `vh` and viewWidth `vw` units and for a moment felt like it's the thing I've been searching for my whole life. But then I tried actually putting content inside and of course something went wrong.

[Example 1](https://jsfiddle.net/4p3xotb8/1/)
[Example 2](https://jsfiddle.net/4p3xotb8/)

Why is this happening and what are some ways to avoid it?

EDIT: I've discovered the answer on my own. The question I was directed to by doctor duplicate talked mostly about some sort of DOM phenomenon called margin collapsing, and the process by which one could reverse its effects... The answers there contained functioning solutions, however the information was anything but helpful (as I did NOT understand it very well), and apparently not really related to the problem my code was facing in the first place. As it turns out all I needed to do was set my element margins to 0. Although I still don't understand why it actually pulling my div down instead of just the content element (`p` or `hx`), and I would have liked some kind of explanation, I would have been satisfied with "set your content elements margins to 0".

Comment: This happens due to [margin-collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)